# Guzzle6 with Google Analytics api

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, guzzle, pageviews

I run a small blog site and display the GA pageviews on posts list.
The problem is the fetching process takes about 20s or more.
To make it faster I found out Guzzle6 api but I don't know how to combine these api's to work together.
What I want to do is to run GA api to get pageviews simultaneously for the posts.

Or if you guys know any other way to get pageviews for each post faster, I will be so much appreciated!

thanks.

for the reference, here's the GA api code I use currently. (which works fine but too slow to get pageviews for multiple posts.)

```
function views() {

require_once 'gapi.php';
$jsonPath = __DIR__ . '/THE-PATH';
$serviceClientId = 'THE-SC-ID';
$pID = 'P-ID';
$slug = get_the_slug_for_each_post();

$ga=new gapi($serviceClientId,$jsonPath);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$dimensions = 'pagePath';
$metrics    = 'Pageviews'; 
$sortMetric = null;
$filter = 'ga:pagePath=@/'.$slug;
$startDate  = '2015-01-01';
$endDate    = date('Y-m-d');
$startIndex = 1;
$maxResults = 10000;

$ga->requestReportData($pID, $dimensions, $metrics, $sortMetric, $filter, $startDate, $endDate, $startIndex, $maxResults);

foreach($ga->getResults()as$result) {
    $views = $result->getPageviews();
}
    return $views;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [composer file of the PHP API client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/composer.json) you will see that it already uses Guzzle. So, no need for action.

```
"name": "google/apiclient",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Client library for Google APIs",
    "keywords": ["google"],
    "homepage": "http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "google/auth": "^0.11",
        "google/apiclient-services": "^0.11",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "~2.0|~3.0|~4.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~0.3.10|~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2|~6.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.2"
    }
```

To solve your problem I suggest that you download the data in advance (once per day or so) to a database table on your server, then query the data per page from the local database. Not only this is faster, it also helps you to avoid hitting the query limit for the API as your site grows.